# How do I create an EFCore Sqlite context that supports external extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Full file encryption can be compiled in.
https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

A Json loadable extension can be added at runtime.  https://sqlite.org/json1.html

What I can't find in the EFCore (6) docs is anyway to load the JSON loadable extension, or to use a precompiled SQLite other than the Nuget package.  Should I Add Sqlite as a compilable to my solution and set the flag for the compilation and then add a reference to the project?

Seems like there should be something in the Options Builder to allow the use of any loadable extensions.

And I should have some way to pass the password for the full file encryption.  I'm not finding anything in the docs about either of these possibilities

Comment: If you have access to the connection object, perhaps this will work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/extensions

Comment: Make this an answer and I'll gladly accept it.